# WPF: Read ResourceDictionary as string by URI

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uri, resourcedictionary

Is it possible to read **xaml** file (that is in the project) as string with, for example, relative uri?

```
"/ProjectName;component/Themes/Default/Core.xaml"
```

The reason why I cannot create new ResourceDictionary or XamlWriter is that XamlReader discards some attributes while loading resources and there is not way to get at after that.